# d3v4 on change event real time binding data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to bind an input range value to a text while `range.value` on change.

My simple function:

```
function change() {
    var para = document.getElementById("#cValue");                       
    var node = document.createTextNode(cValue); 
    cValue = sliderValue; 
    para.appendChild(node);
    console.log("sliderValue:" + cValue);
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ookangzheng/rk9jfox5/4/).

Comment: Does my answer helped you?

Comment: Yes, Thanks a lot

Comment: Then I would be really grateful if you Upvote/Accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should not use `#` when referring to any DOM object through id. When you are using `d3` then it's fine to use `#` but same can't be apply when you are using `document`.

Second, mistake was you calling slider value change method wrongly.

Third, you were trying to append text object instead changing the value of paragraph.

I updated you fiddle and it's working. You can find it here : 
https://jsfiddle.net/L8d1sLu4/